# Get count(*) > 1 field value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query which uses the membership table and user table. What I like to do is for emails that have a count(*) > 1, I also like to show UserName as well.

```
 SELECT au.UserName, am.Email       
 FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] am
 join aspnet_Users au
 on am.UserId = au.UserId
 group by am.Email
 having count(*) > 1
 order by email
```

Not sure how to do it. I tried using max(au.UserName) but that will just give me the first username and not all of them

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved ..Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table #t1
(
id int
)

insert into #t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
#t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `count` window function.

```
select userName,Email
from (SELECT au.UserName,am.Email, count(*) over(partition by am.Email) as cnt_per_email       
      FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] am
      join aspnet_Users au on am.UserId = au.UserId
     ) t
where cnt_per_email>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add au.UserName to the group by clause.

```
group by au.UserName, am.Email
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` with a sub-query.

```
SELECT 
    au.UserName, 
    am.Email       
FROM 
    [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] am
    join aspnet_Users au
    on am.UserId = au.UserId
where
     am.Email in (select Email from [aspnet_Membership] group by Email having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not seem to work as select UserID from [aspnet_Membership] group by UserID having count(Email) > 1 does not return any values.

Comment: Then you don't have anyone with more than one email... or are you trying to return users who have shared email addresses?

Comment: Yes that have shared email addresses between multiple accounts

Comment: Edited @NatePet

Comment: @NatePet You need to explain your goal in your question, because the query you gave constrained the query to a single account with `on am.UserId = au.UserId`